# async whilst not running fn

Tags: javascript, async.js

I want to use async.whilst function and probably missing something badly when I'm getting just the first console.log on the output.

// app.js file

```
var async = require('async');
var count = 0;

async.whilst(
    function () { 
      console.log('first')
      return count < 5; 
    },
    function (callback) {
      count++;
      console.log('second')
      callback()
    },
    function (err) {
      console.log('third')
    }
);
```

// run the script

```
$ node app.js
first
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [the documentation](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#whilst): you need a callback also for the first function

```
var async = require('async');
var count = 0;

async.whilst(
  function (callback) {
    console.log('first')
    return callback(null, count < 5);
  },
  function (callback) {
    count++;
    console.log('second')
    callback()
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('third')
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `callback` inside your **first function**, `async` make calls to subsequent function when the `callback` gets invoked. your code should be

```
async.whilst(
    function (cb) { 
      console.log('first')
      cb(null,count < 5); 
    },
    function (callback) {
      count++;
      console.log('second')
      callback()
    },
    function (err) {
      console.log('third')
    }
);
```